# What does command cat /etc/group mean

Tags: linux

I have used a command called 'cat /etc/group' what does this command mean and do.Can you tell me what each part of the command does please use simple terms.

Comment: Did a Google search for "linux cat command" not find anything at all?

Comment: no not really it was all technical launage which i didn't understand, becase i am new to linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answer to your question explained better than any of us ever could with this command:

```
man cat
```

Comment: The `man` command prints a manual describing the function of a certain command. So if you run `man cat`, then you get the manual page for `cat`.

Comment: thankyou so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It prints to standard output the contents of the file at the location `/etc/group`

Comment: Can you tell me what each par of the command does

Comment: @user12311: What part don't you understand? `cat` is the name of the command. `/etc/group` is the argument to the `cat` command; it specifies the file whose content it prints.

Comment: what does the cat command do.Plus what does the other command like etc and group do.

Comment: @user12311: Exactly as already stated, the `cat` command reads the contents of a file and prints it to the output.  If you don't know what a *file* is then you may want to start with some more basic introductory tutorials to, well, general computer usage.

Comment: thankyou i now understand it.

Comment: can you help me with this command.I dont know what the '-G' is for , in the command 'sudo usermod -a -G group user'

Answer (score 0):

Ok so cat outputs the file, which (in your case) contains basic info about groups.
If you are interested in what are the groups just click [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/users_and_groups)

Comment: Can you tell me what each part of the command does.